# angular-tree-control not rendering data when options attribute provided

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [angular-tree-control](https://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/#multi-selection), I tried with some example, it working fine, but when I add options attribute to enable multiSelect, it is not rendering tree-control anymore. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/veq2p7mc/) is what I did.

If you remove options attribute, it works fine.

```js
 

angular.module('app', ['treeControl'])
  .controller('myController', function() {

  })
  .directive('treeview', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'temp.html',
      link: function($scope, elem, attr) {
        $scope.treeOptions = {
          multiSelection: true
        };
        $scope.selectedNodes = [];
        $scope.treedata = createSubTree(3, 4, "");

        $scope.lastClicked = null;

        function createSubTree(level, width, prefix) {
          if (level > 0) {
            var res = [];
            for (var i = 1; i <= width; i++)
              res.push({
                "label": "Node " + prefix + i,
                "id": "id" + prefix + i,
                "i": i,
                "children": createSubTree(level - 1, width, prefix + i + ".")
              });
            return res;
          } else
            return [];
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
.chzntree-search-results .treeselect-title {
  margin-left: 41px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/angular-tree-control.js"></script>

<link href="https://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/css/tree-control.css" />
<link href="https://wix.github.io/angular-tree-control/css/tree-control-attribute.css" />

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <span treeview></span>
  </div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="temp.html">
    <treecontrol class="tree-classic" tree-model="treedata" selected-nodes="selectedNodes" on-selection="showSelected(node, selected)" options="treeOptions">
      label: {{node.label}} ({{node.id}})
    </treecontrol>
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated to [here](https://jsfiddle.net/veq2p7mc/32/)

Just handle the tree model before DOM render

```
   compile: function compile(elem, attrs) {
   return {
                pre: function preLink($scope, element, attributes) {
   $scope.treeOptions = {multiSelection: true};
        $scope.treedata=createSubTree(3, 4, "");
        $scope.selectedNodes = [];


    function createSubTree(level, width, prefix) {
      if (level > 0) {
        var res = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= width; i++)
          res.push({
            "label": "Node " + prefix + i,
            "id": "id" + prefix + i,
            "i": i,
            "children": createSubTree(level - 1, width, prefix + i + ".")
          });
        return res;
      } else
        return [];
    }
  }
};
```

}